# Printing a 10x10 grid with "P" at the beginning and "T" at the end

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a 10x10 array setup to print out a grid using periods "." I need help figuring out how to print out the grid where there is a "P" in the upper left hand corner in array element [0] and a "T" in the bottom right hand corner of array element [99].
Should look something like this:

```
P.........

..........

..........

..........

..........

..........

..........

..........

..........

.........T
```

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Adventure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char grid[][]= new char[10][10];

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
                System.out.print(".");
                System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not printing your grid, you are printing dots and new line symbols. I am assuming that this is homework, so I am not writing any code for you, just hints of what to do:

- Go through your array with two nested loops, and set its content to all dots
- Set `grid[0][0]` to `'P'`
- Set `grid[9][9]` to `'T'`
- Go through your array with two nested loops, and print the character at `grid[i][j]`
- Call `System.out.println()` after each line (it is not necessary to pass it an empty string)

Once this base version is working, you can work on optimizing it. For example, you could switch to printing `new String(grid[i])` in a single loop instead of using two nested loops. But that would be "points for style": first of all, you need to get the most basic thing work.

Comment: How would I set the contents to all dots for the two nested loops?

Comment: @KevinSanchez Like this: `grid[i][j] = '.';`

Answer (score 1):

you must set your array elements:

```
grid[0][0] = 'P';
grid[0][1] = '.';
grid[0][2] = '.';
...
grid[i][j] = '.';
...
grid[9][9] = 'T';
```

but you must use loops to do it automaticly.

After that you can print elements:

```
System.out.print( grid[0][0] );
```